How to perform conditional formatting on Oracle Apex Bar Graph
I want to perform some simple formatting for a bar graph in Oracle Apex. In a numerical graph, given a value, I want to draw a horizontal line across the y axis at that value and any bars that contain values below that line should be coloured red and otherwise green. For example, if this is my [Bar Graph] and the value inputted is 33, only one bar should be green and the others red
I am not sure what to try, my graph source is an SQL Query and I know there may be some solutions that use the CASE query in connection with some CSS, but I am unsure about how to go about this. I appreciate any solution.

To do that, you would need a query like the following where your case expression evaluates the column quantity similar to your use case:
select 
  case 
    when b.quantity > 50 then 'gold'
    when b.quantity <= 30 then 'red' 
    when b.quantity > 30 then 'green'
    else 'blue'
  end colors
from eba_demo_chart_orders b

Regarding the CSS you mentioned, you can use exact HEX codes like #fff instead of gold.

For more information, see the dropdown: Bar Chart (Series Colors) Information from the sample app https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/r/apex_pm/sample-charts/bar
Also note that the sample apps cover a wide variety of features that you can install, reverse engineer and learn from.

Thank you that was very helpful and have figured out the colouring. Do you have any idea how to draw the horizontal line, am still struggling with that.
